# Error at Declare statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, function

Error at Delcare statement

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 3

```
CREATE FUNCTION  temp(arg1 VARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE modCount INT;
CASE
      WHEN arg1 =' '
    THEN SET modCount = 0;
    ELSE
    SET modCount = (ROUND ((LENGTH(arg1 )- LENGTH( replace ( arg1 , ',', '') )) / LENGTH(','))+1 );
  END    
    RETURN (modCount);          
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the default delimiter (;) with something. Here I am using ^^^ to avoid this error.

After your function definition, you can set it back to ;

```
DELIMITER ^^^ 
CREATE FUNCTION  temp(arg1 VARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS INT BEGIN
            DECLARE modCount INT; CASE
              WHEN arg1 =' '
            THEN SET modCount = 0;
            ELSE
            SET modCount = (ROUND ((LENGTH(arg1 )- LENGTH( replace ( arg1 , ',', '') )) / LENGTH(','))+1 );  END CASE;
            RETURN (modCount);   END^^^ 
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delimiters.

```
DELIMITER //

-- your create function definition here

//
DELIMITER ;
```

The `DELIMITER` statement changes the standard delimiter which is semicolon ( ;) 
to another ( here //).

Here in your code,the first ; semicolon is found at line 3. So it tries to execute till the ';'.
But that syntax is invalid.
So you got the error

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I missed delimeter as well as End case.. thank you very much.

I have a doubt, IN MYSQL is it possible to use temporary table in a view?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "CASE" and some semi colons. Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  temp(arg1 VARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE modCount INT;
    CASE
        WHEN arg1 =' ' THEN SET modCount = 0;
        ELSE 
           SET modCount = (ROUND ((LENGTH(arg1) - LENGTH(replace(arg1, ',',''))) / LENGTH(',')) + 1);

    END CASE;    

    RETURN (modCount);          

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I missed delimeter as well as End case.. thank you very much.

I have a doubt, **IN MYSQL is it possible to use temporary table in a view?**